# Programmatically add an mms to the inbox

Tags: android, sms, mms, attachment

using 1.5, i want to programmatically create an mms and insert it into inbox.

working code for inserting sms is

```
ContentValues val = new ContentValues();
val.put("body", "This is test message!!");
val.put("address", "1234");
val.put("date", "1234567891204");
getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), val);
```

this code is working, i need same thing (if possible) for inserting mms (i.e. text message with e.g. .png attachment) or may be close to this code.

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i figured out a way myself.
AFAIK, you cannot insert message with attachments (programmatically) in conversations. A new messaging thread is not created for a message with attachments (don't know why). So you can insert a dummy sms for the recipient, then insert your message with attachments and delete the dummy sms.
Hope it will help someone!

Comment: Sorry to disturb you, mind to share your MMS insertion code ? I'm trying to do that for 3 weeks now without success. I've even tried your way to add a dummy sms and delete it then. But i failed :s